# How to fix height of LI to be high as the other LI

Tags: html, css

I've an unordered list like this:

```
 <ul style="float:left;">
     <li class="book">
     <div>title sdfdfdsfdsfds sdfsdfsdf dsfsdfsdf fdgsdfsdf</div>
    </li>
    <li class="book">
    <div>title</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The height of the li should depend partially from the content of li(div height). But if the height of the inner DIV becomes higher than another div inside another li all the div should assume the same dimension of the larger div.

I tryed with:

```
div { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
```

and setting the li

```
float: left;display: inline-block; height: 100px;
```

but nothing changed. If the content of the first DIV causes the div to resize, the other DIV will not assume the new 100% height. How can I solve this ?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but does it have to do with the fact that you have mixed up the `:` and `;` in the `li` style?

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, to automatically adjust things to the same height based on their content, they must be part of a **table row**. Try this:

```
<ul class="booklist">
  <li class="book">
    <div>title <br>sdfdfdsfdsfds <br>sdfsdfsdf dsfsdfsdf fdgsdfsdf</div>
  </li>
  <li class="book">
    <div>title</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
.booklist { display: table; float: left; }
.book { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Note that unlike a set of inline-block items, table rows will not auto-wrap to multiple lines, so if that is your goal, you cannot accomplish this with CSS and must add some JavaScript, such as to adjust the heights.

Comment: Yes..but if I put to the DIV an height: 100%; the DIV doesn't resize to fill the remaining space..Don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (put the li elements inside the div element):

```
<ul style="float:left;">
    <li class="book" >
       <div style="display: inline-block; height: 100px;">
         title sdfdfdsfdsfds sdfsdfsdf dsfsdfsdf fdgsdfsdf
       </div>
    </li>    
    <li class="book" >
      <div style="display: inline-block; height: 100px;">
        title
      </div>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

DISCLAIMER: inline styles there for ease of reference:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding you but this:

> all the div should assume the same dimension of the larger div.

is going to happen anyway.

If you are trying to maintain some consistency between the li elements try something like this:

```
li {float: left; width: 100px; border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden; }
```